# R Tools for Visual Studio - R Project Template Missing

Tags: r

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and I then installed the R Tools for Visual Studio. When I click on New Projects, I don't see R listed as a template type. However, I watched a Microsoft Build video, made in May of this year, and R did show up on the presenters copy of VS when he created a new project. Anyone know why I don't see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see R Tools menu? If yes, what is version of R Tools in Help About? If no, try uninstalling and reinstalling R Tools.